# In book class, make the titlepage environment successively displayed

Tags: page-breaking, titles

I use several `titlepage` environments on book document class as

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
This page is title page
\end{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}
This page is title page too
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

but I want the title page successively displayed (just clear single page) instead of clear double page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't use two column format, the simplest way is to redefine the `titlepage` environment:

```
\renewenvironment{titlepage}
  {\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
   \setcounter{page}{0}% Comment out if you don't want to reset the page number
  }
  {\newpage}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\patchcmd` from the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to change the definition of `\titlepage`.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
This page is title page
\end{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}
This page is title page too
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```